# Alfresco Share: how to modify Activity List dashlet?

Tags: list, android-activity, share, alfresco, dashlet

I want to extend the behavior of the activity list dashlet in Alfresco Share.
The problem is that the default dashlet only display news about the creation of a DataList and nothing about the update of a row.

I'm using Alfresco 4.2.d

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

The dashlet only displays activites that are posted. So first of all you'll need to ensure that a update of an DL entry creates an activity post.

- You can use Alfresco.Share.postActivity (in share.js) to post an activity via browser JS.
- You can also add a custom Policy/Behaviour to post an activity via ActivityPostService directly in repo layer

Comment: First of all thx for the reply.
Which is the best solution? Can you please explain better the first one?

Speakinh about the second solution, when you talk about "policy/behaviour", does you mean to add some rules?

Thx

Comment: adding a behaviour/policy means to write some Java code (http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-behavior/behavior-article.pdf)
Your question regarding the best solution depends on your detailed requirements & your skills (backend vs. frontend)

Comment: about my skill, i know very well java (3 years of j2se development), but in fact i don't know nothing about the alfresco java development/api. i'll take a look to the pdf you've linked, but can you suggest me the simplest solution?

thx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure the update of DL entry create the activity post.

you can share afresco post for activity browser with add a custom policy directly with repo layer, you can add a custom policy or post service with a repo layer

Comment: please, could you please explain me how to do this?